# I can't filter firestore for React native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I can't get any output in console, I want to sync 'title' to 'asdasd' which I want to do.

```
 async function getPost (){
          
        const li = [];
      const storeDb=firebase.firestore()

      const postDetailsRef = collection(storeDb,'Post');

      const postQuery = query(postDetailsRef,where('title', '==','asdasdt'));

      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(postQuery);

      querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
        console.log('hop doc',doc.data())
      })
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried this with my firestore and it's working properly

```
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const test = query(collection(db, 'development', data.id, 'messages'), where('index','==', 1));
    const testSnapshot = await getDocs(test);
    testSnapshot.docs.map(doc => 
    {
      console.log( doc.data())
    });
```

because you are using `getDocs` and `query`, i assume you use modular firebase v9. Try changing

```
const storeDb=firebase.firestore()
```

to

```
const storeDb = getFirestore(yourfirebaseApp);
```

according to this [firebase document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)